# how to hide qty box from out of stock product page

Tags: php, javascript, css, ce-1.9.1.0, html

There is a `quantity box` on each Magento product page. I'd like to hide this quantity selector on `Out of Stock` product pages.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: They should be hidden. Are you using custom theme?

Comment: @Reindex'EmAll yes i'm using custom template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change view.phtml in this way:

change this code:

```
?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
   <div class="qty-container clearfix">
       <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
       <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

to this:

```
<?php if(!$_product->isGrouped() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
   <div class="qty-container clearfix">
       <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
       <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The template file you'll want to edit is `catalog/product/view.phtml`
The following code does exactly what you're looking to accomplish and it is taken from `rwd` theme.

```
<div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

    <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
        <div class="add-to-box">
            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                    <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
    <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <div class="add-to-box">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```